# redux call nested function

Tags: reactjs, redux

Lets say I have created a function in actions like:

```
export default function login(){
  function my_init (){
    // some initialization goes here or some logic
    dispatch(some_actions, response)
  };
  function check_func() {
    console.log("Inside check_func") ------> It is never get printed.. 
    this.my_init()
  }
}
```

Now I want to call this function in my component:

```
class Login extends Component{

    render() {
    const { login, actions } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={actions.login.check_func}>Click to login</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  login: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

I have mapped dispath and state  to props. 
But When I click on the button my actions is not called.

Need help.

Comment: Is there a reason you use `this` in `this.my_init()`?

Comment: I am calling the methods inside same class.. I guess that is the way.. I am new to javascript.. Any help on my question ?

Comment: There is no class there, you are exporting a function.  Try to drop the `this.` at the front of the `this.my_init()` call.  Also, `despatch` is misspelled.

Comment: My main problem is when I click the button <button onClick={actions.login.check_func}>Click to login</button> check_func is not called.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
export default function login(){
  function my_init (){
    // some initialization goes here or some logic
    dispatch(some_actions, response)
  };
  function check_func() {
    console.log("Inside check_func")
    this.my_init()
  }
}
```

Functions in JavaScript are not classes. Most importantly, functions defined inside other functions are *not* exposed outside of the parent function automatically. In order to access them, they must be returned from the outer function. For example:

```
export default function login(){
  function my_init (){
    // some initialization goes here or some logic
    dispatch(some_actions, response)
  };
  function check_func() {
    console.log("Inside check_func")
    this.my_init()
  } 

  return { my_init, check_func }; 
}
```

Then to access it, use the return value of the outer function:

```
<button onClick={actions.login().check_func}>Click to login</button>
```

However, given how you *want* to use it, you probably just want to export an object with methods:

```
export default {
  my_init (){
    // some initialization goes here or some logic
    dispatch(some_actions, response)
  },
  check_func() {
    console.log("Inside check_func")
    this.my_init()
  }
};
```

This will allow you to reference the function the way you are currently:

```
<button onClick={actions.login.check_func}>Click to login</button>
```